# ZFS Creation Gives LVM Error

Tags: lvm, zfs

Attempting to create a ZFS Pool on an SDD But Keep running into various errors.

lsblk Output for the drive is:

```
sdc                           8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sdc1                        8:33   0 232.9G  0 part 
│ ├─Evo250-vm--303--disk--1 251:0    0    10G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--401--disk--1 251:1    0    32G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--404--disk--1 251:2    0    32G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--405--disk--1 251:3    0    32G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--101--disk--1 251:4    0    10G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--304--disk--1 251:5    0    10G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--305--disk--1 251:6    0    10G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--600--disk--1 251:7    0    10G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--301--disk--1 251:8    0    10G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--110--disk--1 251:9    0    20G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--302--disk--1 251:10   0    10G  0 lvm  
│ ├─Evo250-vm--306--disk--1 251:11   0    10G  0 lvm  
│ └─Evo250-vm--308--disk--1 251:12   0    10G  0 lvm  
└─sdc9                        8:41   0     8M  0 part
```

Command I use for ZFS creation:

```
zpool create -f pool1 /dev/sdc
```

Error I receive:

```
the kernel failed to rescan the partition table: 16
cannot label 'sdc': try using parted(8) and then provide a specific slice: -1
```

If I try

```
zpool create -f pool1 /dev/sdc1
```

I get

```
cannot open '/dev/sdc1': Device or resource busy
cannot create 'pool1': one or more vdevs refer to the same device, or one of
the devices is part of an active md or lvm device
```

I have also tried

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
```

With error

```
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdc’: No space left on device
238476+0 records in
238475+0 records out
250059350016 bytes (250 GB) copied, 796.689 s, 314 MB/s
```

I am running Deiban 8.6 / Proxmox 4.4

I have also tried cfdisk /dev/sdc and tried partitioning into various types to no avail.

Any direction to get sdc into a pool would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `wipefs -a` for the disk devices you'd rather *surely* want to have re-initialized; then reboot. **BEWARE**: incorrect use would severe reduce chances of data recovery.

As a matter of finding out what is actual run-time use of `sdc1` you can invoke

`sudo dmsetup ls --tree`

that would give out current mappings of the device-mapper.